# Left Join After Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I'm having trouble with this query that fetches sorts forum topics on the number of replies in a different table. I tried this with Left join before the where but some data was left out in my while loop.

```
SELECT forum_topics.*, COUNT(forum_posts.comment_id) AS replies 
FROM forum_topics 
WHERE forum_topics.subcat_id = '$subcatid' 
LEFT JOIN forum_posts 
ON forum_topics.topic_id=forum_posts.topic_num  
ORDER BY replies DESC
```

It gives me this as an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN forum_posts ON 
forum_topics.topic_id=forum_posts.topic_num ORDER BY r' at line 1
```

This is the query that was working before:

```
SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE subcat_id = '$subcatid' ORDER BY date DESC
```

To echo I use:

```
$getChildCategory = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($get); 
if($num == 0){ echo 'No Posts';}
else{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
```

When echoing I only get 1 result with the left join but with the old one I got 2 which is what I expected.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `mysql_query` in new applications as it is way too dangerous. Use PDO or `mysqli` instead. Please use [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the clauses are in the wrong order.

This is the correct syntax (**EDITED per comments below**):

```
SELECT `forum_topics`.*, COUNT(`forum_posts`.`comment_id`) AS `replies`
FROM `forum_topics`
LEFT JOIN `forum_posts` 
ON `forum_topics`.`topic_id` = `forum_posts`.`topic_num`
WHERE `forum_topics`.`subcat_id` = '$subcatid'
GROUP BY `forum_posts`.`topic_num`
ORDER BY `replies` DESC
```

When you perform any sort of `JOIN`, you create a sort of "virtual table" that is an amalgamation of all tables involved. The where clause operates on this "virtual table", so if you think about it it only makes sense for the `WHERE` clause to go after this table has been created.

Comment: read my post please i already tried this but it only fetched some data

Comment: Then your query is incorrect. Making your syntax invalid isn't going to change anything.

Comment: Maybe you wanted an `OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: @kdogisthebest then your query is incorrect. You can't fix bad logic by using the wrong syntax.

Comment: @Matt Wouldn't it be brilliant if you could? Maybe I could just write every application as `read my mind() { unless you know better() }` and it would all work like magic.

Comment: @kdogisthebest Please show some sample data, the results you expect and the results you are getting.

Comment: @DaveRandom +1 for making me shoot water out my nose (I'm enjoying my lunch right now)

Comment: @kdogisthebest You're not required to accept my answer just because it's the only one... let's try and get a solution first :-) So presumably what you are wanting to do is fetch all posts that belong to a topic with a given `subcat_id`? And I take that when you run without the `JOIN` it returns all the topics you want to look at?

Comment: yes and id also like to fetch the count from the other table. I believe whats wrong is my type of join because there is only one forum_post and one of the topics has an id of 1 which is what the topic_num is in the forum_post. So any idea which type of join id use to get all even if theres no corresponding forum_post

Comment: @kdogisthebest OK I'm thinking you need a `GROUP BY` (if understand what you are trying to do) - try the edited query above.

Comment: Worked GREAT only problem with this query is you put `` in COUNT which caused an error. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @kdogisthebest Oh yeh sorry I missed two out, I'll fix it now for future visitors.